# Sending a HAR file saved on Chrome via Java

Tags: java, har

A HAR file can be saved in Chrome opening Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+J), then clicking on the Network Tab, then finally right clicking and choosing save entry as HAR.

After downloading this, how can I send a HTTP request using this file as input in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check http://www.frogthinker.org/projects/harlib, which allows you to easily read HAR files and map them to Java objects. The next step would be writing some factory that would build Http Requests on base of Har objects.